# actionBar icon of SliderDrawer [Smartface Platform]

Tags: android-actionbar, cross-platform, smartface.io

I added the sliderdrawer object. It show the Smartface icon in the action bar. I can't change this icon. Do you have a documentation about this object.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 this.actionBar.homeAsUpIndicator = "your custom icon";
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using beta release.

You can change the icon by using .icon property of SliderDrawer.

But ,the icon must be set before adding the drawer to the page once its added cannot be changed